# byte-wise operation on multibyte native types idomatically

Tags: c++, c++17

In C I would, without hesitation, write the following:

```
uint32_t value = 0xDEADBEEF;
uint8_t *pValue = &value;

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
{
    pValue[i] ^= 0xAA;
}
```

But in C++17 I'm faced with two constraints from my code scanner

- Use "std::byte" for byte-oriented memory access.
- Replace "reinterpret_cast" with a safer cast.

The latter coming into effect when my C lizard brain inevitably tries to force a typecast.  So how exactly do I idiomatically accomplish what I'm trying to do?  In my googling I ran past memcpy in and out of the data of a vector but that feels goofy.

Comment: If you replace `uint8_t *pValue = &value;` with `std::byte* *pValue = reinterpert_cast<std::byte*>(value);` does it still complian?

Comment: The compiler will allow it but the code scanner gets annoyed about the use of reinterpret_cast.  That was what my C brain said as well but if these two code scanner rules are any indication this apparently is not very idiomatic/safe.

Comment: What scanner do you use?  casting a `T*` to a `byte*` is explicitly allowed by the standard.

Comment: SonarQube.  It's definitely not fault proof, some stuff I have to ignore.  But I had wondered if there was an idiomatic phrase which allows what I want and satisfies the code scanner's set of rules in a performant way.  To be fair, it classifies these issues as "smells" rather than issues or compilation stopping problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true: ... AliasedType is std::byte (since C++17), char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

So, `reinterpret_cast` is an [eldritch abomination](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/what-would-count-or-define-as-an-eldritch-abomination/46832#46832) but won't give you any error no matter what type pointer you give it, **except** that these 3 ways of naming bytes is allowed.

So a "safer" cast would be a function that specifically only gives you an array-of-bytes view of an arbitrary object, rather than exposing the `reinterpret_cast` and making the reviewer check that the type used is allowed and it's used in the idiomatic way.

Meanwhile, you need to write an old-fashioned counting `for` loop *and* index the pointer to get to each element.  You can have the "safer" (more specific, more targeted) feature take care of that too, by providing a result that is a proper range of bytes, not just a pointer to the beginning.

The easiest way is to use `std::span`.
Just off the top of my head:

```
template <typename T>
auto raw_byte_view (T& original)
{
     constexpr auto sz = sizeof(T);
     auto& arr = reinterpret_cast<std::byte(&)[sz]>(&original);
     return std::span<std::byte,sz>(arr);
}
```

I've not tried that, but it appears that to get the compile-time size version of the `span`, you have to give in an array reference, not separate pointer,length arguments.  You can cast to *reference* to an array, and it includes the size as part of the type.

### discussion

Returning `span` as a wrapper around the array reference is nicer than trying to deal with the array reference itself, because it's too easy to mishandle the array *reference* as it has to be kept as a reference.  You could accomplish the same thing with a pointer to a `std::array` which unlike the C array works like any normal type.  But we want reference semantics — the returned thing is a reference into an existing object, not a thing to be copied.  So it's better to use a type that represents this indirection rather than stacking another pointer on top of a value-based type.

### end discussion

Now you can write:

```
for (auto& x : raw_byte_view(value)) {
   x ^= std::byte{0xAA};
}
```

Comment: That's a great deep-dive.  I love `raw_byte_view`.

Comment: I don't think `std::static_extent` is standard though?  It should be replaced with `sz`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I was referencing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span which shows to be part of the C++20 standard.  I may have misread it (quickly) trying to find the right constructor, as it's rather more complex the the original (`gsl::span`).  
If you don't have that, use [`gsl::span`].  It seems odd that you would have to specify `N` in two different template arguments at the same time; the class and the specific constructor. 
(https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#SS-views) instead.

Comment: Ah, you're right I think:  it looks for `N == extent` _or_ `extent==dynamic`.  I guess the former gives you the compile-time size support.   Look at this code (after any other "exercise for the reader" issues are found) via compiler explorer with -O3 and see what happens when you use a uint32 and the compiler tracks the size all the way through 

Comment: Yeah, the second template param is the size, with `std::dynamic_extent` being a _magic number_ `-1`.  https://godbolt.org/z/146356G3s

Answer (score 2):

`reinterpret_cast` visually declares that you are converting a pointer type to an (aliasing-safe) unrelated pointer type, and enforces that there is no runtime overhead.  (By comparison, C casts can be rather difficult to spot in code, and some will have runtime costs)

`std::byte` replaces `char` and its aliases to designate that you are **not** working with a printable character or an "integer", in the mathematical sense.  It is an arbitrary collection-of-bits *byte*.

```
uint32_t value = 0xDEADBEEF;
std::byte *pValue = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(&value);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
{
    pValue[i] ^= std::byte{0xAA};
}
```

Comment: Let me add, to assure OP, that this use of `reinterpret_cast` is OK: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing "Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true: ...  AliasedType is std::byte (since C++17), char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes."